# using generic to declare data-type in @Input angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to use generic type in @Input in angular component like this, `@Input('list') list: <T>;`

this is not working    `'(' expected.ts(1005) Public property 'list' of exported class has or is using private name ''.`

Please help, how can I do it.

Comment: Use `@Input('list') list: T;`

Comment: @fridoo, its giving error , Cannot find name 'T'.ts(2304)
Public property 'list' of exported class has or is using private name 'T'

Answer (score 1):

Make your Component generic

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}!</h1>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class HelloComponent<T>  {
  @Input() name: T;

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('hello', typeof this.name)
  }
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-khusgc?file=src/app/hello.component.ts

Comment: I also want to mention, that it is necessary to add `<T>` at the end of your class-/componentname. I overlooked that part